# why with eclipse compiler via ant to build,it is error and it is ok in eclipse when compiling same code and using same jdt and jdk(1.6)?

Tags: eclipse, ant, eclipse-jdt

I am using ant to build source code using the same eclipse compiler that is used in eclipse.The problem is:

1. with eclipse compiler via ant to build, it is error and it is ok in eclipse when compiling same code and using the same jdk(1.6) and jdt.
   the mainly jdt jar as follow: (org.eclipse.jdt.core_3.13.100.v20171123-1049.jar,org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.apt_1.3.60.v20171129-1553.jar,org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.tool_1.2.51.v20171122-1403.jar).
   But if use jdk(1.8) and same jdt, ant(eclipse compiler) can compile successfully.
2. Some of the resulting class files are different in size than the class file generated by compiling within eclipse. for example:

   - eclipse compiler via ant jdk1.8 and within eclipse jdk1.6 and same jdk.
   - eclipse compiler via ant jdk1.6, lower jdt and within eclipse jdk1.6 and high jdk.

why are these?As prescribed I'm telling Ant to use the eclipse compiler, like:

```
<target description="compile project with Eclipse compiler" name="build-eclipse-compiler">
        <property name="build.compiler" value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter"/>
        <antcall target="build"/>
</target>
```

and the with eclipse compiler via ant to build, the error as follows:

Class org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter could not be loaded because of an invalid dependency.

This is ant building error :

[image: ant build error]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "and jdk(1.6)". Is that that jdk that is running the build? Note that recent versions of JDT need to run on 1.8. The error you are seeing could be the indirect consequence of any class not found or no such method error. Things are differently, if you want to _compile against_ jre 1.6, which is if course possible also with recent versions of JDT.

Comment: "and jdk(1.6)" means that I use ant to build(ant build-eclipse-compiler -lib ...). What I can't understand is why in eclipse can be compiled successfully with jdk1.6 and recent version of jdt.

Comment: Your answer doesn't help to understand the role of jdk(1.6) in your attempts. Please answer: do you use jdk 1.6 to run ant, or is 1.6 the system library that you compile against (so that _your_ program can later run on jre 1.6)?